# Redirect tomcat output from console to /logs

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

My default tomcat configuration sends logs to the console, but i want it to be in /logs directory.
How can i configure tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Use a logging framework like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). There you can configure to log to a file rather than the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a comprehensive [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging) in the Tomcat WIKI. If you are referring to logging produced by web applications, then these should use a logging framework, as suggested by Bozho and the FAQ. Regarding messages produced by the Tomcat itself (catalina.out), you can configure the logging.properties file at conf directory.

Comment: I am using a log4j.properties, the one available in tomcat 7 documentation. but i cannot see full logs.